# DB Upgrade Fails when creating Getting Started Dashlet

Tags: upgrade, database, dashlet, error-page

CiviCRM 4.6.11 to 4.7.1 Update
Joomla 3.4.8

Error page during DB upgrade utility:

```
[Error: Add Getting Started dashlet]

Error Field
Error Value
Type
DB_Error
Code
-3
Message
DB Error: constraint violation
Mode  16
UserInfo
INSERT INTO `civicrm_dashboard_contact` (dashboard_id, contact_id, column_no, is_active) SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `civicrm_dashboard`), contact_id, 0, IF (SUM(is_active) > 0, 1, 0) FROM `civicrm_dashboard_contact` WHERE 1 GROUP BY contact_id [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`famcafe_sandbox`.`civicrm_dashboard_contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_dashboard_contact_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]

DebugInfo

INSERT INTO `civicrm_dashboard_contact` (dashboard_id, contact_id, column_no, is_active) SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `civicrm_dashboard`), contact_id, 0, IF (SUM(is_active) > 0, 1, 0) FROM `civicrm_dashboard_contact` WHERE 1 GROUP BY contact_id [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`famcafe_sandbox`.`civicrm_dashboard_contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_dashboard_contact_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: constraint violation in unknown on line unknown
- DB_Error: DB Error: constraint violation in unknown on line unknown

Exception trace
#
Function  Location
0 CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
unknown:unknown
1  call_user_func(Array, Object(DB_Error))
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:931
2 PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error('DB Error: constr…', -3, 16, Array, 'INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php:976
3 DB_Error->DB_Error(-3, 16, Array, 'INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:564
4  PEAR->raiseError(null, -3, null, null, 'INSERT INTO `civ…', 'DB_Error', true)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1905
5  DB_common->raiseError(-3, null, null, null, '1452 ** Cannot a…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:895
6  DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php:328
7  DB_mysql->simpleQuery('INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
8  DB_common->query('INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2435
9  DB_DataObject->_query('INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1627
10  DB_DataObject->query('INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:334
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query('INSERT INTO `civ…', true)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1267
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('INSERT INTO `civ…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSeven.php:272
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FourSeven::addGettingStartedDashlet(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '4.7.alpha1')
unknown:unknown
14  call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
15  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
16  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
17  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
18  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
19  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
unknown:unknown
20  call_user_func(Array)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:278
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:86
22  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:54
23  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:116
24  civicrm_invoke()
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40
25  require_once('/home/famcafe/pu…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:392
26  JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/home/famcafe/pu…')
/home/famcafe/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:372
27  JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_civicrm')
/home/famcafe/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:98
28  JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()
/home/famcafe/public_html/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:152
29  JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()
/home/famcafe/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:252
30  JApplicationCms->execute()
/home/famcafe/public_html/administrator/index.php:47
```

Comment: for whatever it is worth, I tried s smaller increment to 4.6.12 and the same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this and solved it.

I've opened a ticket [CRM-18264](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18264) to address this issue, and I've submitted a pull request for both 4.6LTS and 4.7.  They've been merged, so you just need to upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6.15+ or CiviCRM 4.7.5+.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! I'm trying it tonight after business hours have ended for the client and I'll let you know if it worked for me. Much appreciated.