# Registration Profile Selection Reverts after Save & Close

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla

Joomla 3.4x

Civi 4.6.10 (can't update due to error described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9407/db-upgrade-fails-when-creating-getting-started-dashlet))

PHP 5.5.30

Online registration is enabled, primary registration uses Profile A on top, and Profile B on the bottom.

Additional Registrations use Profile C. Originally the client had selected Profile B for additional registrations, but realized they didn't need to collect that information.

If you remove Profile B from Additional Registrations and then Save and Cancel to close the Event, Profile B does not appear in the form.

If you remove Profile B from Additional Registrations and use Save & Close, the form reverts to using Profile C and B.

Very maddening as the default that most people take is Save & Close.

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a resolution?